# Is there a way to serialize Dictionary<string, string> with an inner object?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have next dictionary

```
 var invoiceParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 invoiceParams.Add("order_id", "111");
 invoiceParams.Add("goods", "[{amount:100, count: 2}]");

 var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invoiceParams);
```

Can I serialize it into next JSON with newtonsoft.json?

```
{
   "order_id":111,
   "goods":[
      {
         "amount":100,
         "count":2
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: It would serialize with quotes around it because it is a string.  Just write proper class representations of your data and serialize/deserialize as normal

Comment: It probably won't *deserialize* properly, unless the dictionary is more strongly typed.

Comment: You aren't showing where the data that populates invoiceParams is coming from. Do you already have "[{amount:100, count: 2}]" as a string? Is is that something your constructing from another object to try and create the JSON you want?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make it an object?

```
 var invoiceParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 invoiceParams.Add("order_id", "111");
 invoiceParams.Add("goods", new List<object>(){ new {amount=100, count=2}});
 var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invoiceParams);
```

Comment: only i think, `var invoiceParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();`

Answer (score 1):

When I want to output data as JSON, I normally used Named Types. By which I mean plain old C# classes that represent the data structure. They're a good option because they can be used to deserialize the data as well as serialize it. In fact my data models usually sit in a Class Library project all of their own so any producers or consumers can reuse them as needed. Another advantage is that you can put [Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) on the [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), which is useful for customizing JSON.Net.

If I'm feeling a bit more lacking in effort (read: lazy) and don't need the deserialization benefits then sometimes I'll use [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). You can create a new Type "on the fly" so to speak which is the format you want to output as.

Here's an example of using [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) to reformat the data during output.

This is the code working on DotNet Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wLkoLk

This is the code itself:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = new
        {
            order_id = "111",
            isTrue = true,
            rating = 3,
            goods = 
            new []
            {
                new
                {
                    amount = 100,
                    count = 2
                },
                new
                {
                    amount = 9001,
                    count = 1
                }
            }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, new JsonSerializerSettings() { Formatting = Formatting.Indented });

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

And here's the JSON output:

```
{
  "order_id": "111",
  "isTrue": true,
  "rating": 3,
  "goods": [
    {
      "amount": 100,
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "amount": 9001,
      "count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

So what does the Named Type approach look like?

Here's the working DotNet Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/d7sJua

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public class Invoice
{
    [JsonProperty("order_id")]  
    public string OrderId { get;set;}

    public List<Good> Goods { get;set;}
}

public class Good
{
    public int Amount { get;set;}
    public int Count { get;set;}
}

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        var invoice = new Invoice()
        {
            OrderId = "111",
            Goods = new List<Good>()
            {
                new Good()
                {
                    Amount = 100,
                    Count = 2
                }
            }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invoice, new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() 
        });

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

And the JSON output:

```
{
  "order_id": "111",
  "goods": [
    {
      "amount": 100,
      "count": 2
    }
  ]
}
```